# SVG scale transform has motion

Tags: css, svg

Can anybody tell me why this SVG has a motion animation? Only the scale should animate.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HbLkm/

Comment: It seems that they are scaling in relation to the origin 0,0. One way to override that is to center them in 0,0 and move them using an enclosing `g` object. See [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/helderdarocha/pen/cCsgb). Another is to use `transform-origin: center`.

Answer (score 2):

They are scaling in relation to the origin 0,0.

You can override that moving the circles to the origin 0,0, and then use an enclosing `g` object to move them back to where they should be:

```
<g transform="translate(391.1,22.9)">
    <circle class="pulse2" ... cx="0" cy="0" r="9"/> 
</g>
<g transform="translate(457.6,22.9)">
    <circle class="pulse2" ... cx="0" cy="0" r="9"/>
</g>
```

See: [Updated CodePen 1](http://codepen.io/helderdarocha/pen/cCsgb)

Another is to use `transform-origin: center` in CSS:

```
.pulse2 {
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}
```

See: [Updated CodePen 2](http://codepen.io/helderdarocha/pen/lpEkG)